# Array fails to check existing items in angular 8

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have a task to add items in array and deleted if same item is selected for that I have written below code. but it seems like array is failing or my code is having some bug which is causing it to fail.

```
<div class="grp-input">
                        <label class="input-title">Member Search</label>
                        <input type="text" (keyup)="onSearchMember()" [(ngModel)]="memberName" class="form-control field-font" placeholder="Enter Member Name">
                    </div>


<div class="members-div d-flex flex-row col-lg-6" *ngFor="let member of memberData">
                    <div class="member-checkbox">
                        <input class="checkbox checkmark" (change)="selectMember(member,$event)" type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb1">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img class="member-img" [src]="img" alt="">
                    </div>
</div>
```

**typescript code**

```
memberData: Array<any> = [];
selectedMembers: Array<any> = [];

selectMember(member, e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      if (this.selectedMembers.length == 0) {
        this.selectedMembers.push(member);
      }
      else if (this.selectedMembers.length > 0) {
        const index = this.selectedMembers.indexOf(member.email);
        if (index > -1) {
          this.selectedMembers.splice(index, 1);
        }
        else if(index==-1)
        {
          this.selectedMembers.push(member);
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      const index = this.selectedMembers.indexOf(member);
          this.selectedMembers.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log("selected members",this.selectedMembers);

  }

onSearchMember() {
    var param;
    if (this.memberName) {
      param = {
        "pageNo": 0,
        "pageSize": 6,
        "name": this.memberName
      };
    } else {
      param = {
        "pageNo": 0,
        "pageSize": 4,
        "name": ""
      };
    }

    this.quoteService.get(constants.searchMember, param).subscribe(result => {

      if (result != "") {
        console.log(result);
        this.memberData=result;
      }
      else {
        //swal.fire(result.status, result.msg, 'warning');
      }

    }, error => {
      swal.fire(error.status, 'Opps!Something went wrong.', 'warning');
    });
  }
```

Now everything works fine but when I search member and clear search member input field and select existing item once again then array take it as a non existing element and pushes it.
I'm so annoyed from this. Can anyone help me for this.
and if my explanation is not enough just let me know ill add more explanation to it .

Comment: Can you recreate this in a simple stackblitz? I can see a problem in your code, but am not clear on your intentions.

Comment: actually I have never uploaded code on stackblitz but I'll do it maybe that will help @KurtHamilton

Comment: @KurtHamilton actually there are some limitations on my system as i posted this code from my company's system and they do not allow to access stackblitz and github so I can't upload it there. But if you want full code I can submit that here

Comment: I think a clearer description of what you're trying to achieve would be more helpful. Can you access https://ng-run.com/? That's a stackblitz alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This line `const index = this.selectedMembers.indexOf(member.email);` will always return -1 , where selectedMembers doesn't contains member's emails it contains the whole member object.

so you need to replace that by looping through selectedMembers and check if it has a member with the same email like that

```
const index = getMemberIndex(member.email);

getMemberIndex(email){
  for(let i=0;i<this.selectedMembers.length;i++){
      if(this.selectedMembers[i].email==email){
        return i;
      }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Or

You can use lodash https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash

and get object index by property `const index=_.findIndex(this.selectedMembers,{email:member.email});`

Comment: I will try this and will let younknow